# Delete from a table variable, or make a new one?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am writing a proc. The proc counts the occurrences of certain activities in my database. Any activities which are in the database, but are not used, are removed from the database:

```
-- make table variable of occurrences
DECLARE @occs TABLE(ActID int, Occurances int)
INSERT INTO @occs(ActID,Occurances)
  (SELECT Activities.ActivityID, COUNT(Users.ActivityID) AS Occurances
    FROM Users JOIN Activities ON Users.ActivityID = Activities.ActivityID
    GROUP BY Activities.ActivityID)

-- Delete any activities that no one uses
DELETE FROM Activities WHERE ActivityId NOT IN (SELECT ActID FROM @occs)
```

The end result (displayed on my site) looks a bit like the StackOverflow tag sytem - it displays the name of each activity, and the number of people who do that activity.

Not all users should be included in the count of people in each activity. However, if they are the only user doing that activity, the activity should not be removed. So, I have to populate the occurances table again, after the previous query runs:

```
INSERT INTO @occs(ActID,Occurances)
(SELECT Activities.ActivityID, COUNT(Users.ActivityID) AS Occurances
  FROM Users 
 JOIN Activities ON Users.ActivityID = Activities.ActivityID
  WHERE (Users.CountsTowardsActivityTotal = 1)
 GROUP BY Activities.ActivityID)
```

It is this version of the `@occs` table that is outputted:

```
-- return relevant results.
SELECT a2.ActivityID, a2.ActivityName, occs.Occurances 
FROM
  @occs occs JOIN Activities a2 on occs.ActID = a2.ActivityID
ORDER BY
  a2.Activity
```

So, I need to delete all the rows from the `@occs` table after it is first filled, and put in new data. Alternatively, I could create a new table variable (`occs2`) and use that instead.

What is the right thing to do? Does it make a difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why so many table variables and aggregates and procedural steps?

Your first pair is:

1. Give me all used activities by some user (why GROUP BY?)
2. Delete where not in this list

If you think about this before coding in plain language you have "delete where no users associated":

```
DELETE FROM Activities WHERE NOT EXISTS 
   (SELECT * FROM Users U WHERE U.ActivityID = Activities.ActivityId)
```

Your second one can be done in one query. Just add Activities.ActivityName to the GROUP BY:

```
 SELECT
      Activities.ActivityID, Activities.ActivityName, COUNT(Users.ActivityID) AS Occurances
 FROM 
      Users 
      JOIN Activities ON Users.ActivityID = Activities.ActivityID
 WHERE
      (Users.CountsTowardsActivityTotal = 1)
 GROUP BY 
      Activities.ActivityID, Activities.ActivityName
 ORDER
      Activities.ActivityName
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. As you may have noticed, I'm not very familiar with SQL.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience, DELETE's always cost more, so I would probably just create a new one.  However, I don't see a need to populate the table variable for the first pass at all.

```
--removes activities not used
DELETE FROM Activities
FROM Activities LEFT JOIN Users ON Activities.ActivityID = Users.ActivityID
WHERE Users.ActivityID IS NULL

--do final select
```